# Validating XML file from another website

Tags: php, xml, xsd

I want to validate external user generated XML files to my local XSD schema using PHP.

The DomDocument schemaValidate function require local files

```
(ie: "$objDom->loadXML($feed_at_local_filesystem);"
```

but I want to validate them from another URL, for example :

```
$objDom->loadXML('http://example.com/feed.xml");
```

I'm using this piece of code, but it doesn't work with external XML files

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
/* creating a DomDocument object */
$objDom = new DomDocument();
/* loading the xml data */
$objDom->loadXML($feed);
/* tries to validade data */
if (!$objDom->schemaValidate(PATH_BASE . DS . "carweez.xsd")) :
/* if anything goes wrong you can get all errors at once */
$allErrors = libxml_get_errors();
/* each element of the array $allErrors will be a LibXmlError Object */
print_r($allErrors);
else : 
echo "xml validates!";
endif;
```

Comment: php may not allow loading urls directly. does `echo file_get_contents('http://....')` show any xml? any warnings? if not, you may have to use curl to fetch it to a string, then load the string into DOM separately.

Comment: or `fsockopen` if curl is not available

Comment: Yes, but what if the XML files is larger than 30Mb in size? I'm thinking about that but I'm a little bit worried about the file size issue

Comment: Copy the file to disk first then. 30 MB works well for a local file with DOMDocument AFAIK.